# Struts2 Annotations validate String using RegexFieldValidator

Tags: java, regex, validation, struts2

I am trying to use Struts2 Annotations to validate some fields of a bean.
In this case, I would like to validate a phone number String with a regex.

I found the `@RegexFieldValidator` annotation, so I included in my class and made some tests:

```
  @RequiredStringValidator(message="Phone required.") 
  @RegexFieldValidator( message="Invalid Phone",
    expression="\\([\\d][\\d][\\d]\\) [\\d][\\d][\\d]-[\\d][\\d][\\d][\\d]")
  public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
  }
```

However, the regex expression doesn´t work. I tried even with `"\\d{9}"` and `"[0-9]{9}"`.
Even with `type=ValidatorType.SIMPLE`.

The `RequiredStringValidator` works properly...What´s going on here?

Is it possible to use this validator properly?

Comment: You could consider using a shorter regex, too.

Comment: Are you sure that `phone` variable is being set and it is not `null`?

Comment: Struts version? Version 2.3.12 has broken annotation support which was improved in version 2.3.14 (under Vote now)

Comment: The phone variable is NOT null and I am using Struts version 2.3.12.

Comment: @aloplop85: Now you can update Struts2 version to 2.3.14.

Comment: I´ll try it as soon as possible. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Struts 2 team has fixed the error and now it works correctly in version 2.3.14.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
  <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.14</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried both cases:

**1. Field validation:**

AccountAction.java

```
regexFields = {
        @RegexFieldValidator(fieldName="phone2",
                             regexExpression="\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}",
                             message="Invalid Phone")}
```

**2. Visitor field validation:**

AccountAction.java

`visitorFields = { @VisitorFieldValidator(fieldName="account", message="[Error]",  appendPrefix=true)
        }`

Account.java

`@RequiredStringValidator(message="Phone required.") 
      @RegexFieldValidator(message="Invalid Phone", regexExpression="\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}") 
          public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
@RegexFieldValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD, message="Invalid Phone",
    expression="\\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\\)\\s[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
```

Comment: I write the phone number inside here:<s:textfield label="Phone" name="account.phone"/>   When validating the account bean, anything is accepted as "phone". The @RequiredStringValidator is working properly.

Comment: Put the `validation` interceptor on the stack if it's not already there.

Comment: I am using the "defaultStack" so the "validation" interceptor is included there by default. Also, the other validations are working well.

Comment: Probably you need getters and setters, and annotation for `account.phone`

Comment: The getter and setter were already placed for "private String phone;"                                                               public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
  }
  
  @RequiredStringValidator(message="Phone required.") 
  @RegexFieldValidator(type=ValidatorType.FIELD, message="Invalid Phone",
    expression="\\([0-9][0-9][0-9]\\)\\s[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]")
  public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
  }

Comment: I mean the account, setAccount, getAccount.

Comment: Yes, the Account setter and getter are inside an Action class. As I told before, the RequiredStringValidator is working but the RegexFieldValidator is not doing anything.

Comment: That is the problem you have either put it in the Account and use `name="account.phone"` or put it in action then `name="phone"`.

Comment: In the AccountAction class, in order to validate account fields I put: @Validations( visitorFields = {
    @VisitorFieldValidator(fieldName="account", message="", appendPrefix=true) [...] )